# How to find properties file on classpath?

Tags: java, spring

My project has two modules `persistence` and `services`

**persistence/MySqlDatabaseConfig** looks like

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default")
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:resources/db.properties"),
        @PropertySource(value = "file:/home/y/conf/pryme/db.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class MySqlDatabaseConfig extends JpaCommonConfig {
 ....
}
```

**services/src/main/resources/db.properties**

```
database.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
database.username=root
database.password=
```

also `services` module depends on `persistence` module

When I run tests I see error as

```
Failed to load bean class: com.yahoo.comma.persistence.profiles.MySqlDatabaseConfig; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resources/db.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How can I access properties file correctly?

**UPDATE**
In `services.war`, I see that it is here

```
   374 Wed Jun 11 11:26:16 PDT 2014 WEB-INF/classes/pryme.properties
```

Comment: Where is the properties file? Your application is expecting it to be in a subdirectory called "resources" which is (the subdirectory is) inside a subdirectory that is in the CLASSPATH. So `resources` doesn't need to be in CLASSPATH, but its parent does.

Comment: Its not duplicate. The solution doesn't apply in this case

Answer (score 2):

`src/main/resources` is a default path that maven uses to holds resources.

During compilation/build times, it takes everything in there and puts them at the root of the target runtime classpath.

You need to specify the entry as

```
classpath:/db.properties
```

since it will be at the root (`/`) of the classpath.

Comment: I still see that issue. Are you sure this will even work in case properties file in different module?

Comment: @daydreamer Do you have two files with the same name?

Comment: @daydreamer In a webapp, anything in `WEB-INF/classes` is considered as being in the root of the classpath. If your `db.properties` is in there, the correct way to retrieve it is what I've shown.